# is there a panorama lib to use for ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, panoramas

recently I've been given a project which need to display a spherical panorama view. Normally on iphone i've been using panoramaGL for some time but for ipad, i dont have any luck to use it any more.

I can compile the lib with some minor warnings. but when i try to link the lib to my real project, it just keep telling me that PLTexture is not there. it says

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLTexture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-PLTexture in panoTestViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please anybody can help me out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and  noticed that although I included PanoramaGL xcode project, its lib (*libPanoramaGL.a*) was not selected to build with the target (that little checkbox in the top right list of XCode).

Once I selected the checkbox, the problem went away, but the bulider was stuck on a similar error with PLResources as the current trouble maker. But this might be only my problem, cause I went to the PanoramaGL project, and noticed that PLResources.c and .h were not included in the project.

Once I included them and rebuilt everything - the build succeeded.

Hope this helps,
Oded.