# PanoramaGL on iOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, panoramas

Has anybody used the panoramaGL from http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/ ?
How did you setup the project?
I have changed the base sdk to 4.0 but I am  getting 75 errors.

If not is there any free library to do 360 photo on iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer but look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763978/360-panorama-librarys-for-ios) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420269/is-there-a-panorama-lib-to-use-for-ipad). Although the guy behind PanoramaGL is still working on the lib, It seems that people consider It sort of deprecated. I managed to correct lot of the errors to have It compile well on my iPad, but the user experience looking around the panoramic photo, it's not so good like I'd like It to be. The documentation about the tesselation algorithm It's not easy, so I preferred starting over.

Comment: Thx man but the link is broken. I have fallowed the instructions from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/panoramagl.aspx  but nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The last version of PanoramaGL runs fine on iOS 4 or better. Please check http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/ and download HelloPanoramaGL example that uses hotspots.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample Xcode project source code called HelloPanorama in the [Downloads section](http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/downloads/list) of the PanoramaGL. It is very self explanatory, but here is a [walk thru tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60635/Panorama-360-iPod-Touch-iPhone).

The non-ARC errors for a project with ARC could be fixed using the [following instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). If you'll get any ** errors, just replace **variableName with *__autoreleasing *variableName.

That did it for me.

Note: also if your PLSpherical2Panorama class renders a messed up panorama, you need to have at least one hotspot on it to fix it. Took me some time to find out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid having the hotspot image in the middle of the image you can use this. It's an empty image and it's completely transparent :) http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ImmagineVuota.png