# How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, manual-retain-release

I am using ARC successfully in my project. However, I have encountered a few files (e.g., in unit tests and mock objects) where the rules of ARC are a little more fragile right now. I recall hearing that there was a way to disable ARC on a per-file basis, though I have been unable to find this option.

Is this possible? How do I disable ARC on a per-file basis?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274209/why-maintaining-retain-count-is-not-required-in-arc-enabled-project?__=2075832026

Answer (score 2183, accepted):

It is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for those files.

You add compiler flags in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. You have to double click on the right column of the row under *Compiler Flags*. You can also add it to multiple files by holding the cmd button to select the files and then pressing enter to bring up the flag edit box. (Note that editing multiple files will overwrite any flags that it may already have.)

I created a sample project that has an example: https://github.com/jaminguy/NoArc

[image: xcode]

See this answer for more info:
[Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files)

Comment: So, the place to add this flag isn't too intuitive. But, in Xcode 4, in build phases, and compile sources, there are actually two columns. One for the file name, and another for the compile flags for that one file. This is where you enter this specific compiler flag.

Comment: Can you specify for a directory, i.e., for all files in a directory? What about for a Group?

Comment: No directories. Only one single file at a time in the build settings :(

Comment: @casademora you cannot get enough upvotes for this piece of information. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this works but Xcode 4.2.1 still generates unsightly ARC errors on the editor window, although it eventually compiles just fine. You might want to put all your non-ARC files into a static library and link that to your main target.

Comment: I did this but Xcode refactor cleans my flag and throws errors in the files. I run the refactor convert to ARC and the flag is not there anymore. Any help

Comment: @adib - restarting XCode after adding the compiler flag got rid of the ARC errors for me.

Comment: @casademora you can select multiple files at once - but then don't doubleclick but hit RETURN. then just add the `-fno-objc-arc` and it will be added to all selected files. **edit** just saw the answer below this one :(

Comment: After applying this compiler flag I was still getting errors.  I had to click Product -> Clean and then I was able to rebuild my project successfully.

Comment: thanks a lot. just for people who didn't know, if you can't find the file you want in the compile source, press the "+" button to add files

Comment: Note on **multiple flags**: use **spaces** to separate them.

Comment: Note that editing multiple files will overwrite any flags that it may already have.

Comment: This works for me after adding complier flag I restart Xcode.and got rid of ARC.

Answer (score 464):

**Disable ARC** on **MULTIPLE files:**

1. Select desired files at Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources in Xcode
2. **PRESS ENTER**
3. Type **-fno-objc-arc**
4. Press **Enter** or **Done**

;)

[image]

Comment: Thx! Been looking for this feature a long time. Double-clicking doesnt work when selected multiple rows, but pressing enter does. So weird.

Comment: Oh wow. I'd spend all my karma to upvote this again. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: this seems not work on Xcode 4.3.3 anymore. double click or press enter on the selected files doesn't bring up the dialog for putting in the -fno-ojbc-arc flag, anyone has a workaround for this?

Comment: I had 4.3.3 and now 4.4 DP7 and it still works just fine. Try restarting Xcode, restarting machine and repair permissions.

Answer (score 45):

For Xcode 4.3 the easier way might be: Edit/Refactor/Convert to objective-C ARC, then check off the files you don't want to be converted. I find this way the same as using the compiler flag above.

Answer (score 38):

It is very simple way to make individual file non-arc.

Follow below steps :

Disable ARC on individual file:

1. Select desired files at Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources in Xcode
2. Select .m file which you want make it NON-ARC
   PRESS ENTER
   Type **-fno-objc-arc**

Non ARC file to ARC project flag : `-fno-objc-arc`

ARC file to non ARC project flag : `-fobjc-arc`

Answer (score 36):

Note: if you want to **disable ARC for many files**, you have to:

1. open "Build phases" -> "Compile sources"
2. select files with **"left_mouse" + "cmd"** (for separated files) or **+ "shift"** 
   (for grouped files - select first and last)
3. press "enter"
4. paste `-fno-objc-arc`
5. press "enter" again
6. profit!

Answer (score 22):

Just use the `-fno-objc-arc` flag in `Build Phases`>`Compile Sources`

Answer (score 14):

1. Select Xcode project
2. Go to targets
3. Select the Build phases section
4. Inside the build phases section select the compile sources.
5. Select the file which you do not want to disable ARC and add -fno-objc-arc

[image: Disable ARC for a particular file]

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to disable ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) for particular file in Xcode.

**Select Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Select File (double click) -> Add "-fno-objc-arc" to pop-up window.**

I had encountered this situation in using "Reachibility" files.

This is shown in below figure :

[image]

Answer (score 12):

use -fno-objc-arc for each file in build phases

Answer (score 12):

The four Mandatory Step as explained in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgBuGgTrfhA)

```
    //1. Select desired files
    //2. Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources
    //3. Type -fno-objc-arc
    //4. Done
```

Answer (score 9):

Please Just follow the screenshot and enter **-fno-objc-arc** .

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Unity, you don't need to change this in Xcode, you can apply a compile flag in the metadata for the specific file(s), right inside Unity. Just select them in the Project panel, and apply from the Inspector panel. This is essential if you plan on using Cloud Build.[image]

Answer (score 7):

I think all the other answers are explaining how to disable MRC(Manual Reference Count) and enabling ARC(Automatic Reference Count).
To Use MRC(Manual Reference Count) i.e. Disabling ARC(Automatic Reference Count) on MULTIPLE files:

1. Select desired files at Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources in Xcode
2. PRESS ENTER
3. Type -fobjc-arc
4. Press Enter or Done

Answer (score 6):

Add flag “-fno-objc-arc”.

Simple follow steps :
App>Targets>Build Phases>Compile Sources> add flag after class “-fno-objc-arc”

Answer (score 2):

Just use the -fno-objc-arc flag in Build Phases>Compile Sources infront of files to whom you dont want ARC to be apply.

Answer (score -1):

GO to App -> then Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Source

Now, Select the file in which you want to disable ARC

paste this snippet "-fno-objc-arc" After pasting press ENTER

in each file where you want to disable ARC.

Comment: your answer does not provide any addition to this old question.

Answer (score -1):

1. select project -> targets -> build phases -> compiler sources
2. select file -> compiler flags
3. add -fno-objc-arc

Answer (score -2):

Following Step to to enable disable ARC

Select Xcode project
Go to targets
Select the Build phases section
Inside the build phases section select the compile sources.
Select the file which you do not want to disable ARC and add -fno-objc-arc

Comment: your answer does not provide any addition to this old question.

Comment: What addition need. if you know better than provide us.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. It is just this question was asked in Jul 11 '11 at 5:21. There are too many answers with the same answer that don't add any useful information...I suspect that someone downvote you for that reason...

Comment: can you give me some brief on it.